# htaccess mod_rewrite redirect to directory without displaying on url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site called www.example.com and I have my php files in it. I store all my working files in www.example.com/site. I want to view the site in www.example.com instead, without moving my site content. What can I do?

This is currently what I am typing in .htaccess. It will redirect my site to www.example.com/site but I think the url is ugly

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(/.*|)$ /magento$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: So at present `www.example.com` is going to `www.example.com/magento/`?

Comment: Do you also have to serve things from the root (ie `www.example.com/`) or is all the site in `www.example.com/site`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see if i understood this correctly.

You have a domanin, www.example.com, and on this domain you want to display the content of a directory, www.example.com/site !?

If this is the case then you need to change the document root

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you must consider :

If I understand your request, you are accessing some PHP files using `www.example.com`, but what you want is to access `www.example.com/site`, but without the `/site`, right ?

So basicaly, what you're looking for is NOT rewrite, it's just pointing your domain to the good folder, which is `/site`, right ?

- If you're using Apache2, you have to edit your apache's configuration file in `/etc/apache2/site-available/default` (or remplace `default` with the name of the virtualhost you may have created).

In this file, look for the directive `DocumentRoot`. It should lead to the "root" directory of your pages (the one you access typing www.example.com)
I think you just have to append `/site` to this `DocumentRoot` and then reload your apache2 with `service apache2 reload`
You're website `www.example.com` will now lead to the correct directory.

If it's still not working, you must consider looking into magento's admin, because magento is rewriting url according to the `Base URL` you specify inside `Admin / Configuration / general / web`.
You'll have to modify `Base_URL` in both `Secure` and `Un-Secure` sections.

Then it should work fine.
I would comment out the Rewrite bloc you're using at the moment, or maybe I didn't fully undestand what you want to achieve.